# How to update a table column with random values within a range in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, random

I have a table with 3 columns: 
 - `PRIMARY_KEY`
 - `AMOUNTS`
 - `RAND_AMOUNTS` (all nulls)

I want the `RAND_AMOUNTS` column to be populated with following formula:

```
AMOUNT*(0-100 random value)/100
```

So for example if the amount row let us suppose is 10 and the random value generated for the row is 10 then `RAND_AMOUNT` should be `10 * 10 / 100 = $1`

Answer (score 8):

[dbms_random()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_random.htm#i998095) is what you are looking for:

```
UPDATE the_table
   SET rand_amount = (amount * dbms_random.value(0, 100) ) / 100
WHERE amount IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly :) How come i am not seeing precision in my rand_amount all of them are whole numbers hmm.

Comment: @venky80 - check the rand_amount column to see if it is defined with a scale of 0 (e.g. number(9,0) ).  If so, it will only store whole numbers as scale is the number of digits allowed after decimal.

Answer (score 4):

```
update yourtable set rand_amounts = dbms_random.value * amount;
```

Comment: +1 nicely done. This deserves more upvotes. @hal9000, it was probably downvoted by someone who doesn't realise that `dbms_random.value` returns the same thing as `dbms_random.value(0,100)/100`. Them's the breaks :)

Comment: And for integers between 1 and 4 (inclusive): `ceil(dbms_random.value() * 4)`

Answer (score 2):

Using:

```
dbms_random.value(lower-value-limit, upper-value-limit)
```

should do what you're looking for.